# Webpack modules are undefined

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core

I am getting following error at runtime in angular 2 + .net core project:

> Prerendering failed because of error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
>   at **webpack_require**

The error is occuring at this line modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, **webpack_require**) in main-server.js.